# Asp.net Sitemaps

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

I have been strugling with the following problem.Please help
I am using a menu control and populating it with the sitemap.

I have a sitemap provider which looks like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
      <siteMapNode url="" title="Home"  description="" roles="*"  >
        <siteMapNode url="~/Default.aspx" title="PRA Profile" description=""roles="Partner"  >
             </siteMapNode >

        <siteMapNode url="" title="PRA Profile1" description="" roles="Partner">

          <siteMapNode url="~/New.aspx?id=1" title="Partner View"  description="Partner View"> </siteMapNode >
        </siteMapNode >
          <siteMapNode url="~/About.aspx" title="Estimator"  description="~/Test.aspx" roles ="Admin" >
      </siteMapNode >
        <siteMapNode url="~/About.aspx?id=3" title ="Reports" description ="" roles="Admin">
             </siteMapNode>
       </siteMapNode>
    </siteMap>
```

I have added the securityTrimmingEnabled="true" in the web.config

My problem is if I enter an URL in the parent node then the roles attribute isnt working eles it works fine.

if in the parent node i give the url then roles attribute fails.if i dont give the url 
        and add child nodes then the roles based show/hide of the menu works perfectly.
        I have to show only parent node when a "non-admin" logins in and show same screens as child nodes when a admin logs in along with the other screens.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The Roles attribute is an enhancing attribute.  In other words, it enhances the security trimming that is part of your url/role based authentication settings.  Security trimming is done based on the url's security settings in the web config (or other url/role based authentication mechanism).

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178428.aspx

If your url based authentication mechanism is using the web.config to control your url based authentication you'll need to add a location element with authorization to your web.config for the url that you're attempting to control access to:

```
  <location path="PageWithAuthorization.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow roles="Allowed_Role"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

This is the underlying source of authorization.  When the page listed above is part of the sitemap and securityTrimmingEnabled = true, only those users that are in the "Allowed_Role" will see the sitemap link.  By adding another role in the sitemap Role attribute, you allow the additional Role to also access the page.